# Timing-Safety in JVM-Languages

Tags: implementation, side-channel-attack, timing-attack

How is it possible to write timing-safe code in JVM-languages (Java, Scala, Clojure...)?
Is it possible to make libraries like BouncyCastle safe against timing-attacks?

I know that even in C it is very hard to get those things right – and in C you can take a look at the resulting assembly-code and at least predict how your target-CPU will execute it.

In JVM-languages, you don’t know how the JVM will translate your code to machine-code or which runtime-optimizations will be performed.

Edit: I’m not really worried about local timing-attacks but about remotely-exploitable ones.

Comment: It's weird that timing-attack defense discussions don't seem to involve callbacks.  Seriously, all you've got to do is wait a constant time after calling the transform; who cares if the result's available before that?

Comment: Remember that in cryptography, "constant time" really means "secret independent time"; It is not important that every application of the algorithm complete in the same amount of time; It is important to make sure that the time taken by the algorithm does not depend on secret information.

Comment: @Nat: adding a wait time does not protect against cache-based timing attacks; it is thus only a partial defence.

Comment: @ThomasPornin What would be a cache-based timing attack in this context?

Comment: @Nat: in that context, the attacker would issue requests to be processed by the target server and use the response time for these extra requests to work out whether the cryptographic operation is still running, or already reached the "waiting loop"; it could also try to see whether some specific memory element was evicted from cache by the cryptographic operation.

Comment: @ThomasPornin Gotcha; discussed that one in my answer.  Really just need to do rate-limiting with provisioning; each crypto-transform limits as though it used the assigned constant-time, occupying a provisioned set of resources that's independent of the rest of the computational setup.  This can be relaxed when an attacker can't reasonably determine the load of the server for efficiency, but works even if they can.

Comment: @ThomasPornin Just curiosity, it looks like no one's mentioned CTR-like modes, where the stream bits can be determined in advance and cached in a pool, to remove any dependence on the secret at cryption time, which seems like an easier method to implement on platforms where multi-threading's hard to do.  Is that approach commonly used?  Presumably with a secondary transform to protect the pool from an attacker who can read arbitrary memory, I guess.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "JVM language", a "compiled language", or an "interpreted language". A language is an abstract mathematical set of rules and restrictions, a specification. Interpretation, compilation, being hosted on the JVM, all of those are traits of the implementation, not the language. There are interpreters and JIT compilers for C and C++, for example, and there are natively compiled implementations of Scala and Java. In particular, TruffleC was a JIT-compiled implementation of C on the JVM, its successor Sulong is a JIT-compiled implementation of LLVM IR on the JVM, you …

Comment: … can use Sulong to run any language for which an LLVM frontend exists (C, C++, Objective-C, Objective-C++, D, Go, Rust, …) on the JVM. So, the very question of "C vs. JVM-based" is non-sensical.

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag You are right... I just aimed at "the normal use-case" where C etc. usually is shipped and run as platform-dependent binary and Java etc. usually is shipped as JVM-byte-code and run in a JVM...
There are even some C→JavaScript-compilers...

Comment: @K.Biermann: Yes, emscripten, for example is a LLVM-to-ECMAScript compiler, so it can be used to run pretty much anything on ECMAScript (either by compiling the program, if it is written in a language for which an LLVM-based compiler exists, or by compiling the interpreter / compiler to ECMAScript and then using *that* to run the program). I believe that this uncommon use-case is going to be less uncommon in the future. E.g., TruffleRuby can use Sulong to interpret Ruby programs together with Ruby C extensions, and early results indicate that this is *faster* than native C, since both …

Comment: … languages are compiled *together* into a *single* Truffle AST, which allows cross-language optimizations, such as inlining across the language barrier. So, given these encouraging results, I would not be too surprised to see Sulong and similar solutions used more. Which means that the assumption "C is natively compiled ahead-of-time" is going to become less safe in the future. At least, that is my prediction.

Comment: @JörgWMittag You may be right there's no such thing as a JVM language, but it's mostly irrelevant because the question is actually asking about JVM language implementations.

Comment: I am no security expert... But what prevents an implementation simply picking some arbitrary time substantially longer than the operation takes, then sleeping until that time is elapsed (minus the time actually doing the operation)?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The theory is: don't try to write timing-safe code in JVM-languages or other essentially-interpreted-but-perhaps-sometime-compiled languages; rather

- Use timing-safe libraries called from the comfort of the JVM-language. Typical example: in a JavaCard that passed Common Criteria evaluation to EAL5+ with AVA_VAN.5 augmentation, it is a safe bet that AES (when available) is timing-safe.
- Avoid needing timing-safety in the first place when possible. Typical example: rather than attempting to compare an alleged 16-byte value to a reference 16-byte value in constant time, draw a fresh AES key, encipher the alleged and reference value with this AES key (with a constant-time AES implementation), then compare the results using any method at hand.
- As a variant of the above, use countermeasures that make timing attacks less efficient, like [blinding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blinding_(cryptography)).

The above tends to work also against side-channel attacks beyond timing, e.g. power analysis.

---

When market pressure dictates otherwise, options are to make as few as possible relatively safe bets; and check them carefully when one has the luxury of knowing the actual targets. For example, when writing

```
// compare two byte arrays so that timing does not leak where a difference lies
public static boolean myEqualByteArrays[(byte[] a, byte[] b) {
    int j = a.length;
    if (j != b.length)
        return false; // arrays are not the same length
    int r = 0; // will stay zero until a difference is found
    while (--j>=0)
        r |= a[j] ^ b[j];
    return r==0; // true if and only if the arrays match
}
```

it is only assumed that

- binary operations `^` and `|` are constant-time (`&` and unary `~` probably are, too, though we don't need that in this example);
- loops won't be exited even when deep analysis of what follows shows that they can.

So far, if I have met anything breaking these assumption, I did not realize it!

---

Example of things that can't safely be assumed constant-time:

- Any use of `if`, `switch`..
- [short-circuit operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) `&&` and `||`
- Logical not `!`
- Array access (e.g. due to cache).
- Integer multiplication (including by a constant): some CPUs have multiplication time dependent on one argument; examples include [this](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0184b/Chdedhfg.html) and [this](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0337e/BABBCJII.html#ftn.id4044980) 32-bit CPUs (kudos to the manufacturer for documenting it).
- Division, of course (including by a constant).
- Operations on larger data types than supported by the combination of the compiler, runtime, and hardware: conceivably, some internal carry might cause a data-dependent timing dependency even in `+` or `-`, e.g. of some 64-bit type internally using 32-bit variables. This a bit less to fear for variable addition than increment, which could be implemented or automagically over-optimized at runtime into: increment low half, and if not zero increment high half.
- Shift: timing often depends on the shift count.
- Right-shift by a constant shift: that can depend on the sign or high-order bit of the shifted argument (that is less likely with unsigned types; and in Java, it is less likely with the unsigned `>>>` operator than it is with the signed shift operator `>>`).
- The [selection operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#Conditional_assignment) `?:` ; however, in Java, restricting to built-in signed [2's-complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) 32-bit type `int`, a substitute for `d = (a==0) ? b : c;` might be

  ```
  // compute the OR of all bits in  a  into the low-order bit of  d
  d = (a >>> 1) | a;
  d = (d >>> 2) | d;
  d = (d >>> 4) | d;
  d = (d >>> 8) | d;
  d = (d >>>16) | d;
  d = -(d&1); // duplicate the low-order bit of  d  over the whole  d
  d = ((b^c)&d)^b; // select  b  iff a==0,  c  otherwise
  ```

  and that technique could be extended to, say, constant-time point multiplication on an elliptic-curve over some binary field, if efficiency is truly secondary.

Comment: Side question: isn't checking `a.length == b.length` a bad move? You give a _huge_ help to attacker because he can _quickly_ determine the string length. Shouldn't it be `j = min(a.length, b.length)`? Another side question (sorry): any cryptographic hash may be used to reject wrong inputs (`if (hash(a) != hash(b)) return false;`), to my understanding it won'g give help for timing attacks and when hashes match then even a somehow _naive_ comparison will do the job. All this said I agree...use existing function already made and proved to be safe.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Even if you avoid explicitly checking `a.length == b.length`, you still have to make sure all the array accesses are within bounds. This could mean running `for(i=0; i<min(a.length,b.length); i++)`, which would still leak timing. The only hope is that if the secret is long enough (like 20 bytes), then even if its length is known, guessing its value will be near-impossible.

Comment: @Adriano Repetti: key/challenge length is generally considered to be part of the definition of a cryptosystem, and as such not secret (at least, to the same degree as the value of the key/challenge); and, as explained in the other comment, not leaking the expected length in a timing-safe manner is hard, and I wanted a simple example. Thinking about it again, `if (hash(a) != hash(b)) return false;` **can be attacked by timing** if the comparison is with memcmp and the key has low-enough entropy (e.g. a 7-byte random value, which would be safe if a genuine timing-safe test takes a millisecond).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: the attack goes: try incremental values of `a`. Initialy, submit them for verification to the genuine device, until finding `a1` that fails slower than the others; then compute `h1=hash(a1)` and from then on skip values of `a` which hash does not start with the same first byte as `h1`. After finding a new value of `a2` that fails slower, skip values of `a` which hash does not start with the same first two bytes as `h2=hash(a2)`, and so on. The attack has to test and hash about $2^{55}$ values of `a`, but only about 900 online tests are needed.

Comment: Thank you! You're right `memcmp` will be then be the weak point (does a 4 bytes naive hash has too many collisions to be useful? `CMP` shouldn't suffer of this issue). About array length: well, you can always access array with `a[min(i, a.length - 1)]` and you repeat comparison against last character but _somewhere_ you need to check for length. Great explanation!

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti memcmp isn't Java or Clojure so it's a kinda irrelevant comment.  The OP is specifically talking about high level JVM based languages on a multi threaded /user server.

Comment: @PaulUszak obviously I know `memcmp` isn't Java (but you can call it with JNA, BTW), I asked in comment as _side question_ about comparing hashes...

Answer (score 18):

Writing constant-time cryptographic code is certainly possible in Java or similar languages (e.g. C#). However you have to do it properly.

"Constant-time" here means that the observable time-related behaviour does not depend upon secret data. It does *not* mean that execution time is always the same, but only that the variations are not correlated with the secret data elements.

Some sort-of constant-time implementation strategy, often called "microarchitecture defences", tend not to work well with Java. These strategies are mostly about hitting all relevant cache lines. The Java JIT compiler and the GC make it very difficult, if not impossible, to make sure that any piece of data is at a definite emplacement relatively to cache lines. Microarchitecture defences are already quite fragile when implemented in low-level languages like C (they tend to lose their properties when the hardware vendor decides to change something in their implementation); in Java they are mostly unusable.

On the other hand, "true" constant-time is totally possible, in about the same way as it is done in C. By "true" constant-time, I mean that:

- There is no conditional jump, whose condition depends on secret data.
- There is no memory access whose address depends on secret data.
- Opcodes whose execution time depends on secret data are not used.

You may want to have a look at how such things are done in [BearSSL](https://www.bearssl.org/constanttime.html). BearSSL is written in C (mostly), but everything explained in that page works similarly in Java.

My C code uses `uint32_t` to hold boolean flags, with the convention that "true" is 1, and "false" is 0. It is important here *not* to use boolean values, to dissuade the compiler (C or Java JIT) from using conditional jumps. In Java, you would then use `int`, again with 1 and 0. Alternatively, you might want to use -1 for "true", because it is an all-one pattern that is convenient for bit masks; one good thing in Java is that it guarantees modular arithmetics, and its `>>` operator performs sign extension.

Comment: The _"Opcodes whose execution time depends on secret data are not used"_ part is tricky, and potentially platform-dependent. Who knows if increment of `long` (64-bit) has data-dependent timing on a 32-bit JVM? By extension, who knows that for increment of `short` (16-bit, and also the widest type guaranteed available) on a JavaCard? What about [multiplication on a 32-bit ARM](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0168a/i1000002.html)? Etc..

Comment: @fgrieu: I have written some [documentation](https://www.bearssl.org/ctmul.html) on that subject, for multiplications. In any case, the point here is that while the notion of "constant-time code" is specific to the used hardware, Java does not change things substantially; you can make constant-time code in Java with about the same ease (or unease) as you would have with C on the same hardware. Also, if it runs BouncyCastle, then I doubt it's JavaCard...

Comment: I agree with your reasoning and your approach of eliminating conditional jumps, eliminating data-dependent addresses, and using uint32 0/1 as flags. I asked a similar [question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27865974/839689) a few years ago, and ended up implementing a [Bitcoin ECDSA library](https://github.com/nayuki/Bitcoin-Cryptography-Library/tree/master/cpp/) based on constant-time principles.

Comment: "It is important here not to use boolean values, to dissuade the compiler" - I've got news for you, 21st century compilers aren't going to care. While C compilers now have a `_Bool`type, there's so much legacy code that uses integers as booleans that optimizers look for that pattern. To be safe, use `volatile int crypto_true = 1` and `#define CRYPTO_TRUE crypto_true && 1` (the latter to prevent inadvertent modifications). `volatile` blocks optimizations.

Comment: I second what @MSalters said. The fact that you don't use `volatile` types for timing-sensitive code, makes me (perhaps unfairly?) apprehensive to even try your SSL library.

Comment: @Will "volatile" has nothing to do with the issue of timing-related leaks. Leaks are not about _when_ a value hits cache (as opposed to being kept in a register), but whether that moment (and target address) depends on the value contents. Adding some "volatile" here and then will merely transform unsafe code into slower unsafe code. One way to see it is that volatile impacts static data routing, while constant-timeness is all about leaks coming from dynamic data routing.

Comment: Your notion of static data vs dynamic data seems like a false dichotomy to me. Just because your data may be dynamic in origin doesn't mean the compiler cannot make any assumptions about it. Compilers don't care that boolean flags are held in `uint32_t` types if they can logically deduct from the rest of your code that the variable is never assigned anything beyond a boolean range. If, in addition, it believes it can do a decent job branch predicting the remaining options, it *will* create branches despite any half-assed attempt at "dissuading" it from doing so--unless other fail-safes exist?

Comment: I don't want to antagonistic, but I had a look at your `inner.h` code, and  the "constant-time primitives" you use seem dangerously naive. As the cryptocoding reference you've linked to mentions: "the above measures are best effort: C and C++ have the as-if rule, which gives the compiler freedom to implement operations in any arbitrary manner, provided the observable behavior (timing is not considered observable behavior in such languages) remains unchanged.". The [definition of the as-if rule](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if) also clarifies the significance of using `volatile`

Comment: ([This stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29149817/765294) plus its comments sums up my feelings on this subject.)

Comment: What I mean is that adding "volatile" or not adding it has no influence whatsoever on whether the compiler will or will not infer things about the range of possible values in any given variable. If the compiler feels that a variable is really a boolean in disguise, and wants to branch on it, then it will, even if that specific `int` was marked `volatile` (this does not contradict the semantics of `volatile`).

As for making sure the code _is_ constant-time, the best test is to look as the produced assembly. I often do. Feel free to do it too.

Comment: After some more experimentation and research, I concede that getting `volatile` to give the desired guarantees is more tricky than I thought. Checking the output of produced assembly of every compiler X version V is not a satisfactory measure though, is it? Best to write actual constant-time code in asm, at which point you're better of just linking to the "canonical" openssl routines IMO...

Answer (score 9):

Not in the least.  Forget it.

This is written from my experience which is with Java, but all JVM languages will have similar insurmountable problems.  There are issues with compile time and run time optimisations that make the byte code almost impossible to predict. And the optimisations majorly and subtly change with each major /minor release. You'd have to lock your code to a particular minor version of Java, and if it changed, all your time calculations might be thrown out.

Unfortunately, optimisation management is the easy part for this.  The real problem that makes this impossible is a combination of dynamic threading and garbage collection.  C doesn't have these naively so you can manage them.  Java does it autonomously.

There are at least four different garbage collectors that have features suited to different applications.  All of them kick off unpredictably.  That's the result of hardware abstraction which is the primary purpose of JVM based languages. This is why Java applications can suddenly freeze on you as the JVM chucks out unused objects.

Threading is also dynamically allocated.  That means that you can't deterministically predict which thread is currently executing within a CPU core.  And there may be six threads running in parallel when you simply fire up a JVM to execute a "-version" command.  Indeed, this very unpredictability is exploited in the seeding of Java's SecureRandom cryptographic RNG.  It's true to say that it's chaotic inside a JVM.

And remember what a JVM is sat on.  An fully multi threaded operating system with both hard and soft interrupts.  These just confound the number of threads actually being executed at any one time.  The consequence of all this chaotic behaviour is that you cannot with any level of certainty predict how long a for /next loop in Bouncy Castle will actually take to complete.

The good test is a jet engine.  When Rolls Royce starts shipping turbofans with  ECUs running Java then you'll know it's safe to write time critical code in a JVM based language.  You'll be waiting a while as there's probably no market demand for something to compete with C at the hardware level.

There are projects like Javalution and JRockit Real Time, but these really are projects with ambitions of real time programming.  They're really for smoothing out application execution for a human user.  You would't put JRockit on a small Cortex processor to run Bouncy Castle. 
 And these will still succumb to the fact that you'd need an underlying real time OS, such as those listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_real-time_operating_systems).

Post OP edit:

The edit has made my answer even more pertinent.  The attacker will now be faced with analysis of  server responses entirely overwhelmed with tiny (or not)  but entirely non deterministic time fluctuations. There will not only be the uncertain JVM and OS timings, but also all the network timing /latency issues on top.  To see this effect try:-

```
ping baidu.com
```

and watch the latency.  That's in China.

Comment: A precise GC shouldn't introduce any timing side-channel attacks against crypto code (a conservative GC might), neither should multi-threading.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Yes taking your comment further, is a JVM immune to timing attack even if you can't program it so?  If it's chaos in there, then that should mask the operation of a crypto algorithm, and it's timings will be changing effectively randomly. Hmm...

Comment: I wouldn't want to rely on something as hard to quantify as "it's to complicated to analyze" for security.

Comment: I could just run something like byte code on a custom JVM, but this isn't just limited to virtualization  As long as debug registers exist, it's pretty easy to imagine native code having the same issues.  Every CPU that I know has debug registers that I can use for code profiling, even if those registers are not "public" knowledge.   Protection from timing attacks is pretty much impossible if you have hardware access, particularly if you can be the privileged user.

Comment: I’m not really worried about local timing-attacks but more about remotely-exploitable timing attacks; I’ll clarify my question.

Comment: This is right. And then market pressure dictates [otherwise](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/48878/555).

Comment: This answer presents good facts, but doesn't answer the question. The topic is about execution timing that changes *based on the data values being processed*.

Comment: @Nayuki The point I'm making (obviously badly) is that you can't measure the time it takes to do anything very accurately as the crypto process is swamped with random fluctuations, especially if you're hacking from the US to China. Remember that (now) the question concerns remote exploitation.

Comment: @PaulUszak "remote" doesn't necessarily is US vs. China, it could also be in to data centers on the other side of the same city (or even within the same data center).

Comment: @PaulUszak Unfortunately you are wrong.  The literature is full of side-channel attacks which defeat the blinding introduced by network delays - I don't imagine garbage collection delays will be much worse (in fact they may well be easier - the attacker can just ignore "high" values).  Of course this does involve running more attempts in order to average out the delays, but cryptographers don't usually care much about another factor of 2**20.

Comment: @MartinBonner Sounds like you have the basis for posting another answer...

Answer (score 5):

If all you are worried about is secret independent execution time I think you can do so reasonably also in the JVM.

You can add a built in delay with a timer for constant time execution. You may need to use a non open JVM if you want hard real time constraints for example you will want a pauseless GC. Though you may settle for G1 which under manys workloads will not pause measureably. This will allow you to set a reasonable upper bound on execution time. With a standard JVM you will probably not want to set a 100% gurantee upper bound but this may be good enough. If the attacker can't trigger these extreme scenarios. As an addes protection if the result is not ready by the upper bound alotted time you can multiply your alloted time. So even if the attacker can trigger the extreme load situations the measured encryption time will be severely rounded so he will only be measuring his generated load.

The chaotic nature of this complex systems may add many potential voulnerabilities but also makes exploiting them very difficult.

Regardless also on the JVM we can analyze performance to a great extent and though harder we can look at byte code, JIT code and of course empirically measure various micro steps. We need to remember even with assembly there may be processor level actions going on, out of order execution, branch prediction hyper threading, memory cache and more which affect performance. We don't normally take them all into account but we can test with them, at least under reasonable conditions.

A realtime JVM will allow you to make good hard commitments on runtime and could be usefulll.

Obviously we keep finding new side channels and timing attacks are just a relatively easy to exploit one. With a same physical machine attacker there are manu more venues, such as L3 cache.

Comment: How can you have a deterministic duration timer task on Java?  You can't otherwise it would be halfway to a real time OS, and I don't think that there are any generic server based RTOSs that run on a DELL.

Comment: The timer probably will only gurantee not before semantics. But any delay will be due to other load not secret dependent because any secret dependent calculation has with high likelyhood already completed.

Comment: @PaulUszak You might want to check for "Dell Real Time Operating System Software" and RTOSs like the [iHawk platform solutions](http://concurrent-rt.com/partners/technology-partners/dell/) which happen to run on [Dell PowerEdge servers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Dell_PowerEdge_Servers) if you like to be surprised. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, definitely.  Just use callbacks with a set delay.

For example, say that your cryption transform might take anywhere from 1ns to 500ns; then, just await the authority to use the transform instruction, call it, and have it set the transformed result to some reference.  After 1000ns, have the callback fire, using the result from the predetermined reference.

Since you'll need to slow everything down to the slowest to enable constant-time evaluation, this'll slow stuff down.  But on the bright side, the CPU can do other work before the callback fires, so it doesn't eat all of the CPU time.

Because the CPU time is still affected by the transforms, an attacker who can flood your system and watch the resulting CPU usage might still exploit it, even if that's more annoying.  So if that's a concern, then you'll probably want to add rate-limiting to all crypto evaluations in your program, or have do busy work on the CPU before the callback to ensure that the CPU usage isn't different.

Since this is an asynchronous programming scheme, you'll want to make sure that you're using memory barriers and such, as appropriate, or an attacker can exploit the programming errors introduced by improper multi-threaded coding.

Note that some of the "predetermined" values should probably be checked during operation.  For example, if a transform somehow takes longer than expected, then the wait time for all future evaluations should be adjusted upward accordingly - and probably trigger a key change, just in case an attacker happened to glean some knowledge of the current key from that long-evaluation.

Comment: Time algorithm will execute in is very random. This can be further increased by making cache misses, increased system load etc. This is terrible method for that, especially with "trigger a key change" in long run, when sometimes it isn't as simple as one function call.

Comment: @axapaxa Why does that matter?  Those variations are independent of the cryption transform; an attacker can't use them to launch a timing attack.

Comment: They do matter because this can lead to execution over given time limit, in which case you can't do anything and original execution time will be shown. This method isn't fixing the problem, it's trying to hide it by making execution slower, which it does poorly as it requires key change anyway. Why bother with your fix if you can just change key at high rate? Or we could just use constant time implementation...